# Hashing message using CryptoJS output is different from python hashlib that includes Unicode characters

Tags: python, node.js, cryptojs, hashlib

What I'm trying to do is hash a message but it contains a Unicode charset.

**What I've done so far in NodeJS :-**

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let message = '\x1aSmartCash Signed Message:\n\xabCTxIn(COutPoint(7bb8ad134928a003752beb098471af5a66fc5475ff96b5ba4c2e1c4cbac3aa13, 0), scriptSig=)000000000002c5c2ef4afc588492773e6bbb18e4f2374b6dc159ef257667bd881667906410';
let hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(message).toString();

console.log('hash', hash); // 989c004534c6962293c95a9438bdb926c92c1d8b4dec0f4f1e535defa171e5fe
```

**In Python code the code :-**

```
import hashlib

def to_bytes(something, encoding='utf8'):
    """
    cast string to bytes() like object, but for python2 support it's bytearray copy
    """
    if isinstance(something, bytes):
        return something
    if isinstance(something, str):
        return something.encode(encoding)
    elif isinstance(something, bytearray):
        return bytes(something)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Not a string or bytes like object")

def sha256(x):
    x = to_bytes(x, 'utf8')
    return bytes(hashlib.sha256(x).digest())

def Hash_Sha256(x):
    x = to_bytes(x, 'utf8')
    out = bytes(sha256(x))
    return out

message = b'\x1aSmartCash Signed Message:\n\xabCTxIn(COutPoint(7bb8ad134928a003752beb098471af5a66fc5475ff96b5ba4c2e1c4cbac3aa13, 0), scriptSig=)000000000002c5c2ef4afc588492773e6bbb18e4f2374b6dc159ef257667bd881667906410'

print('hash', Hash_Sha256(message).hex()) # 947270b0b8041a92ba82ef37661b692a4a150532b88de59bf95e965ceb5c07f8
```

As you can see the output from Python is different than NodeJS

The desired output should be the same as Python code `947270b0b8041a92ba82ef37661b692a4a150532b88de59bf95e965ceb5c07f8`

I don't know how to hash the Unicode the problem is these characters (\x1a, \xab).
If I removed the escape character the 2 hashes will be the same.

So **how to hash Unicode characters in NodeJS so the output equals the hash from Python code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` in the Python code is a byte string, i.e. a sequence of bytes. In particular, `\xab` in the message corresponds to the byte `0xab`.

In the CryptoJS code, `message` is a string that is *implicitly* UTF-8 encoded in `CryptoJS.SHA256(message)`. Here all characters beyond U+007f are represented by more than one byte. In particular, `\xab` in the message is encoded to [`0xc2ab`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ab/index.htm).
This leads to different byte sequences in the CryptoJS and Python code and therefore to different hashes.

To achieve the same encoding as the Python code, the *Latin1* encoder must be applied in the CryptoJS code:

```js
let hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(message)).toString();
```

With this, the CryptoJS code returns the same hash as the Python code.